# Extending Doctrine DBAL DateTimeType in Symfony2 while parent __construct is final

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to write DateTime to database in UTC and convert it to users timezone upon retrieval. Every user has his timezone set in database.

**Solution**: Extend the `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType` as described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html) so it would always persist in UTC and when needed convert it back to user timezone in the presentation layer via Twig.

**Problem**: The suggested method converts UTC from the **system** default timezone. To make it work I need to read the actual user timezone in the extended DateTimeType and make conversions with that. So... I do the usual dependency injection and inject SecurityContext as it holds the User Entity together with the timezone value:

```
//TreasureForge\CoreBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types

private function __construct(SecurityContext $security)
{
   $this->tz = $security->getToken()->getUser()->getTimezone();
}
```

and

```
treasure_forge.core_bundle.utc_datetime_extension:
    class: TreasureForge\CoreBundle\DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
    arguments: ["@security.context"]
```

But it throws: Compile Error: Cannot override final method Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::__construct()

I've even resorted to the bad, bad methods like:

```
global $kernel;
$tz = $kernel->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getTimezone();
```

This is wrong in every imaginable way but even then for whatever reason getToken() is sometimes set and sometimes not throughout the request so I have serious doubts in the reliability of this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing that in the Entity?

In your `getDate()` ( or whatever your getter is called ) you should get the user timezone. and again in the setter ( `setDate()` ) you should set whatever time you have to UTC.

Please write your Entity code to be able to provide an example.

Comment: I considered that, but that would result in enormous code duplication across all Entities... Found another way [here](http://jeremycook.ca/2012/06/24/normalising-datetimes-with-doctrine-events/) actually but that looks way overcomplicated for what it does. Thanks anyway!